# Anyone know where a good windows constant list lives

Tags: c++, mfc, constants, visual-c++-6, numerical

I'm trying to set an invalid value to -1.. But I don't like magic numbers.. Anyone know where to find a set of common constants. I'm working in VS6 (ish).

I'm trying to read a file from across a network, and I need a bad value for the total file size,so I know if I got valid info on it.. 0 is a valid size so I can't use that.

Harper Shelby HIT THE NAIL ON THE HEAD.. Just a little thumb. 
He mentioned the win32 constants.. which is exactly what I was thinking about.. Now to find a link :)

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking for? For instance, why don't you define your own constant?

Comment: everyone does this.. I could do it.. But I'd rather use something standard.. Like when you SetLastError... It's always better IMHO to use the values in WINERROR.H

Comment: Ironically, this question has INVALID_FILE_SIZE votes at the moment.  Let's keep it hat way. ;-)

Comment: you can't just ask "hey where do i get an invaid num huh?". it depends on the domain and the specific function you are calling.

Comment: I got an answer! I don't understand the neg vote on questions. It was clear, specific, and answerable. I wanted a general list of some of the consts available in VS. I used -1 as a sample, a use case. 
Perhaps my next question should be what the best lang to learn, or your favorite color coffee mug.

Comment: Maybe because you changed the question half way through

Comment: @baash05, you asked 2 different questions.  Kind of hard to sneak something by with an edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define BAD_VALUE -1
```

EDIT: the original question had no context. The revised question indicates you want an invalid file size and are thus looking for the win32 constants. Look at [windows.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h) i think the constant you seek may be in [windows.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h) or one of its sub-includes. grep your windows include directory ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If -1 is an invalid value for a return value in your system, you should define it internally:

```
const int INVALID_FOO = -1
```

unless C compatibility is needed, in which case

```
#define INVALID_FOO -1
```

would be preferred. If it's a standard MFC or Windows resource, use INVALID_HANDLE or one of the other Win32-defined constants.

Comment: I was looking for the win32 defined constants list.

Comment: i like  enum { INVALID_FOO = -1 };

Comment: @litb: If I'm defining an enum, I like to give it a relevant name, though that can get a bit verbose if you're not careful.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use your own magic number -1 disguised as a Windows constant. This is very misleading.

Suppose I happen to know that INVALID_HANDLE is 0. Is it OK to initialize my pointers with INVALID_HANDLE?

```
char *myMessage = INVALID_HANDLE;
```

How does this strike you?

Comment: As readable.. What's in mymessage.. Oh it's an invalid handle.. I shouldn't use it. Hell who cares what it is.. INVALID_HANDLE could be 43264.. If I test. if(myMessage == INVALID_HANDEL) printf("the message has not been initilized");  works for me...

Answer (score 1):

In VS, Create a new windows console application project. Go into project settings and turn on browse support. Create a C++ file and add it to the project. Type:

```
#include <windows.h>
void main(void) {}
```

into the file. Compile it. Now type INVALID_FILE_SIZE into the file. Right click on it and goto definition of INVALID_FILE_SIZE. VS will open one of the many windows header files full of defined values. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you should be using an unsigned int for file size as a file size is never negative. Now an invalid file size is normally the max int so in the case of using a 32 bit unsigned int it would be 0xFFFFFFFF

i.e.

```
const unsigned int INVALID_FILESIZE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Also if this is on windows, windows.h defines invalid file size all ready (INVALID_FILE_SIZE)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use constants used by WinApi, check out the WinError.h, WinUser.h and WinNT.h files.

Answer (score -1):

It's generally accepted the 0 and 1 (positive & negative) are OK to use directly.

In fact, it'll probably make you code even more confusing to use a variable instead.

Update: OK, you updated your question after I wrote my answer. If you are using "-1" in an arithmetic way, then just "-1" is fine.  If you are returning a error code (and the code just happens to be -1) then you should use a const.

```
 const int INVALID_VALUE = -1;
```

Comment: It really wasn't a question of what to use, but thanks. I mean I was going to use a const/define variable.. I was kinda just looking for some of the standard ones that come with windows programming. like MB_OK or ID_YES, VK_ENTER...  They're easy to read and available.. It was more of a curriosity.

Comment: What is funny is that when ever I ask a real question I get down votes, No one tacks on a comment saying "can you elaborate", or anything. I'm not the most experienced programmer but hey, my questions lead somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
If bytes_read < 0
    // error
EndIf
```

Comment: A. I don't see a list in there, 
B. I don't see a constant in there.
C. since the bytes_read is an unsigned variable it will never be less then 0 (assuming that had anything to do with the question)

Comment: @baash05: "I'm trying to read a file from across a network, and I need a bad value for the total file size,so I know if I got valid info on it.. 0 is a valid size so I can't use that." Looks like some fread()-style function, which returns the number of bytes read, or -1 (which is < 0) on error.